# Find index of array of array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to find the index of an array of array object where it is true. My array:

```
[
 [
  {id: 1, status: false}, 
  {id: 2, status: true}
 ],
 [
  {id: 13, status: false}, 
  {id: 14, status: false}
 ],
 [
  {id: 18, status: true}, 
  {id: 19, status: false}
 ]
]
```

In the case above I should expect index 0 and 2 to be returned.

Comment: There's some real ambiguity in your question/example.  The answer to this question is `[0, 2]`: "What are the indices of the arrays in the outer array that have some element in them with `status` of `true`?"  But it is also the answer to a very different question: "
For what indices are there inner arrays where the value at that index has `status` of `true`?"  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get indices of the elements where [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) items fulfill the condition:

```
input.reduce((acc, arr, i) => (
    arr.some(obj => obj.status) && acc.push(i)
, acc), [])
```

```js
const input = [[{"id":1,"status":false},{"id":2,"status":true}],[{"id":13,"status":false},{"id":14,"status":false}],[{"id":18,"status":true},{"id":19,"status":false}]];

const result = input.reduce((acc, arr, i) => (
  arr.some(obj => obj.status) && acc.push(i)
  , acc), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps in the solution of the problem.

- First traverse the array
- Second check the condition. You can check the condition using two array methods.

  - some: Checks if any of the elements in an array pass a test and returns true or false based on the test.
  - filter: Creates an array based on condition and that's the reason I checked array length in the following code.

```js
const data = [
  [
    { id: 1, status: false },
    { id: 2, status: true },
  ],
  [
    { id: 13, status: false },
    { id: 14, status: false },
  ],
  [
    { id: 18, status: true },
    { id: 19, status: false },
  ],
];

let ret = [];
data.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (x.some((y) => y.status)) ret.push(i);
});
console.log(ret);

ret = [];
data.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (x.filter((y) => y.status).length > 0) ret.push(i);
});
console.log(ret);
```

I have used both **some** and **filter** methods to check the condition and for array traversese I have used array **forEach** method.

Comment: that's a misuse of `filter`. `some` was created to take care of such cases - it clearly states the purpose of the code, using `filter` here just adds an unnecessary cognitive and performance burden.

Answer (score 0):

Basically same solution as from marzelin, but more readable in my opinion. The comma operator in the callback return value can be quite confusing.

```js
const data = [
    [
     {id: 1, status: false}, 
     {id: 2, status: true}
    ],
    [
     {id: 13, status: false}, 
     {id: 14, status: false}
    ],
    [
     {id: 18, status: true}, 
     {id: 19, status: false}
    ]
   ]

//pV=previous value, cV=current value, cI=current index
const result = data.reduce(function (pV, cV, cI) {
    if (cV.some(function (obj) {
            return obj.status
        })) {
        pV.push(cI);
    }
    return pV;
},[]);



console.log(result);
```